# set the audio volume in a JavaFX application

Tags: ubuntu, javafx, pulseaudio

After searching for several hours, I wonder if I'm asking an impossible question.

We have a JavaFX application running on Ubuntu with Pulseaudio.  I want to set the audio volume of the HDMI sink programmatically within a JavaFX application, similar to the effect of the command line:

```
pactl set-sink-volume (hdmi sink) volume
```

but cannot find out how to do this.  I *can* find the `MediaPlayer.setVolume()` method which sets the volume of a particular media-file but I want to set the volume for any subsequent media that are played into that sink, until its volume is set somewhere else.  This is because we launch a browser and want to set the volume of any media that the browser plays.  Surely this must be possible?

Comment: The `volume` property of the `MediaPlayer` is only the volume of said player, which is relative to the system volume, which itself may be relative to the speaker volume (depending on if your speaker's volume is independently controlled). That said, you could probably execute that command via a `ProcessBuilder`. That at least should get your application working. Otherwise you'll probably have to drop into native code and invoke it from Java using JNI.

Comment: Thanks and I most likely will use `ProcessBuilder` but I am surprised that there is no library for doing it.

Comment: There could be a library but I'm not aware of one. Unfortunately, if you're looking for a library recommendation that makes your question off-topic (see the [help/on-topic]).

Comment: I'm looking for a way, not a library.  I'm implementing currently with `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing zero about java, I'll risk assuming that you can bang commands onto the command line.

`pactl list short sinks | cut -f2` will provide a list of defined `sinks`

`pacmd list-sinks | grep "name:" | cut --delimiter=: -f2` will provide a full list including your device names

`pactl set-sink-volume the_sink_name required_volume%` will set the volume as a percentage

`pactl set-sink-volume the_sink_name required_volume_left% required_volume_right%` will set the Left and Right volumes. Other speakers in a more complicated setup would simply be additions to the list of volumes.

You can set volumes by value, rather than %, where 65536 (from memory) is 100%, just drop the `%` character.

I hope you get some mileage out of this.